# Why bash if =~ regex negate a character do not work

Tags: regex, bash

```
test="blah*blah"
if ! [[ ${test} =~ [\*] ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
```

=> failed

```
test="blah/blah"
if ! [[ ${test} =~ [\*] ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
```

=> ok

```
test="blah/blah"
if [[ ${test} =~ [^\*] ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
```

=> ok

```
test="blah*blah"
if [[ ${test} =~ [^\*] ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
```

=> ok ??? WHY ?

What is the secret to use a negate pattern for a character somewhere in string ?

Comment: `*` isn't a special character inside `[...]`; it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: `[^*]` matches `b`, for example. Any char but `*`. What is the problem? Regex matching does not require full string match, it is not glob matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `if ! ... string contains (a single character somewhere)` works but `if ... string NOT CONTAINS ^(a single character somewhere)` do not work.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your suggestion but same result without escaping.

Comment: They all work correctly. You just think `[^*]` will work as `^[^*]*$`, but it would not. See `if [[ ${test} =~ ^[^*]*$ ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi` [here](https://ideone.com/oqF8rb). It does not match `blah*blah` but matches `blahblah`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a bash 4.4.12 and `test="blah*blah"; if [[ ${test} =~ [^*] ]] ; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi` always give me `ok` not `failed` while string contains `*` character even in a new bash session.

Comment: Yes, ***contains***. If it **equals**, it will give you false.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes **contains** ... I have a regex which requires a **do not contains** somewhere in string

Comment: Your last regular expression matches any character that *isn't* a `*`; it does not match a string that contains *no* `*`. That would be `[^*]+`. (`[^*]*` can match the empty string, which is a "substring" of anything.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **SO MANY THANKS !!** I have updated my final regex pattern and it works. Regex is really a science !

Comment: @chepner **THANK YOU** for your explanations. I really appreciate. I need to do more test using your example to sure that I have understood.

Comment: My example is basically what @WiktorStribiżew posted earlier (I missed that), but I omitted the anchors you need to ensure you match the entire string, not just an acceptable substring within `test`.

Comment: @chepner, so here in the example given by @WiktorStribiżew `^[^*]*$` will match a `string` from start `^` to end `$` which does **not contains** (0 or 1 ?) or more occurence of `*` `[^*]` and you said that `[^*]*` can match an empty string (empty is 0 or more occurrence) while `[^*]+` is 1 or more occurrence. Am I OK ?

Comment: Right, `[[ "" =~ ^[^*]*$ ]]` will succeed, because the empty string contains consists of 0 or more non-`*` characters. `[[ "" =~ ^[^*]*$ ]]` will not, because it does not contain 1 or more   non-`*` characters.

Comment: @chepner you mean `[[ "" =~ ^[^*]+$ ]]` will not succeed.

Comment: Right. Sigh, I thought I changed that after the copy-paste.

Comment: I've tried summarizing the discussion here in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression (no need to escape `*` inside a bracket expression)

```
[^*]
```

matches any single character that is *not* an `*`. Because regular expressions are not implicitly anchored, as long as *any* character in the string is not a `*`, the match succeeds. Anchoring it

```
^[^*]$
```

matches *exactly* those one-character strings that are not `*`. It won't match any longer string.

If you add a `*` after it, you get a regular expression that matches 0 or *more* consecutive characters that are not `*`. Anchoring it gives you a regular expression that matches any string (including the empty string) that consists of only non-`*` characters.

```
^[^*]*$
```

If you only want to match non-empty strings, makes sure the string starts with non-`*` character, than check that the rest (if any) are also not `*`.

```
^[^*][^*]*$
```

That can be shortened by using `+` instead of `*` for repetition. (`*` matches 0 or more; `+` matches 1 or more.)

```
^[^*]+$
```